# RxJava- flatMap-toList

Tags: java, rx-java

I have below sample code using flatMap and toList(). Can someone tell me whether the below code will hang sometimes? (the actual code with the similar approach hangs in my production env), I can't upload my actual code so i just give sample.

```
public class RxZipFlatMapTest {
@Test
public void testZipFlatMap() {

    Observable.zip(getDummyList(), getActualList(), new Func2<String, String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String call(String s, String s2) {
            return "hi " + s + "   " + s2;
        }
    }).toBlocking().first();


    System.out.println("Done");

}

private Observable<String> getActualList() {
    return Observable.create(new TestObservable()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
}

private Observable<String> getDummyList() {
    return Observable.create(new TestObservable2()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
}

private abstract class TestAbstractObservable implements Observable.OnSubscribe<String> {

}

private class TestObservable extends TestAbstractObservable {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

        Set<String> strList = new HashSet<>();
        strList.addAll(Arrays.asList("pranesh", "uma"));
        Observable.from(strList).flatMap(Async.toAsync(new Func1<String, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(String s) {

                return s;

            }
        }, Schedulers.newThread())).toList().toBlocking().single();
        subscriber.onNext("hello ");

        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}

private class TestObservable2 extends TestAbstractObservable {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
        Set<String> strList = new HashSet<>();
        strList.addAll(Arrays.asList("sunu", "lakshmi"));
        Observable.from(strList).flatMap(Async.toAsync(new Func1<String, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(String s) {

                return s;

            }
        }, Schedulers.newThread())).toList().toBlocking().single();
        subscriber.onNext("hi ");

        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}
}
```

And this is the thread dump in prod

```
Thread 29724: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt() @bci=1, line=836 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int) @bci=72, line=997 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(int) @bci=24, line=1304 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await() @bci=5, line=231 (Compiled frame)
 - rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(rx.Observable) @bci=46, line=461 (Compiled frame)
 - rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single() @bci=8, line=341 (Compiled frame)
```

Thanks
Pranesh

Comment: I can't see anything in this example that would hang. If you are using `toList`, make sure your source actually completes otherwise `toList` may never emit anything. Also make sure you have the latest RxJava (1.2.5 as of writing this).

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd, I couldn't reproduce the problem with my test case, I will check more on toList as you suggest.

Comment: @akarnokd - here the source for toList is output of flatMap right? and do you think is there any way to replicate this?

Comment: `Async.toAsync` is finite so the input to `flatMap`, `Observable.from(strList)` in your example, might be something infinite in your original code.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd, I am not sure how the strList is infinite and i don't know how it is possible. strList value is defined size.

Comment: If you know you have finite sources, then the problem might be somewhere else. The best thing would be an example that reproduces the problem reliably, by for example, putting a loop around the whole thing and see if that hangs.

Comment: Do you do the `doAsync()` in your production code also on the `Schedulers.newThread()`? If not that may be the cause. If thread pool on which you are trying to do the blocking operation is empty this exception may be thrown.

Comment: Yes We have toAsync() in production code also. I tried to reproduce it in my test case but unfortunately I couldn't.

Comment: Can you try to add a [timeout](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html) and log it? Just to be sure...

Comment: sure @JonesV, i am also trying to reproduce it in my test case.